# Swing buttons and FillRect

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

Newb to Java, and running into something that leaves me scratching my head.  I'm trying to make a GUI that has a black background to draw lines on to simulate a group of 7-segment displays.  In addition, I will have a series of Jbuttons.  The problem I'm running into is I can do one or the other, but not both.  I can use fillRect() in the JFrame's paint method to draw a black rectangle, but if I create a JPanel, add Jbuttons to it and add the JPanel, I only see one button.  If I take out the paint method, all the buttons appear, but I have no black box.  Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can use fillRect() in the JFrame's paint method

Don't override the paint() method of a JFrame.

For custom painting you override the `paintComponent(...)`method of the JPanel. Then you add the panel to the frame.

You can than add components to the panel normally and they will be painted on top of the background.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

> Newb to Java,

Keep a link to the above tutorial for examples of all Swing basics.